# Different soundex values php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, soundex

I'm trying to create a mysql query which will select soundex equivalent surnames from a data base.
In php I've produced the soundex code by:

$sxname = soundex($name);

and then I built the mysql query

```
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM database
WHERE soundex(surname)
LIKE '$sxname'"
;
```

This works fine for a lot of surnames, but not for others - such as CAWS. The php soundex value for CAWS is C200 but the mysql value comes out as C000.

Is there a solution to these differences ?

I did try to use a function so both were created in php:

```
function mysql_soundex($name)
{
    $snname = soundex($name);
    return $snname;
}
```

and call it up in:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
FROM database
WHERE mysql_soundex('surname')
LIKE '$sxname'"
;
```

But that didn't work either.

Comment: Your second approach will never ever work. You cannot declare functions from PHP for MySQL to use.

Answer (score 3):

Let MySQL only do the soundex conversion:

```
$query =
        "SELECT * FROM database
        WHERE SOUNDEX(surname) = SOUNDEX('$name')";
```

... or the strictly equivalent syntactic sugar:

```
$query =
        "SELECT * FROM database
        WHERE surname SOUNDS LIKE '$name'";
```

Comment: Thanks - I thought it would be straight forward, I just couldn't see it.

Comment: A problem I've now found is that the mysql soundex is far looser than the php soundex and doesn't match standard soundex coding - so I've gone with adding another field to the database to hold the php soundex code for each surname.